# What special markup options are there in Discussions and how to use them?

Tags: steam

I noticed some users markup their forum posts to render an interactive object. For example this button will open a trade window with the user:
[image: Steam Discussions special markup for trade offers]

Hovering over these images, will show a detailed tooltip view of the item:
[image: Steam Discussions special markup for tooltip item view]
***[View in browser/Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards/discussions/2/864974467249084928/#c558752449727782816)***

[Formatting help](http://steamcommunity.com/comment/ForumTopic/formattinghelp) doesn't mention any of these options. How is it done, and what else can be done? Is this formatting defined somewhere?

Comment: Please take another look at the new answers, because the question you marked as Accepted only answers part of your question and it looks like you were asking for a complete list of all things that can be formatted.

Comment: @Keavon Thanks, I have a bad habit of early accepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## YouTube Videos

Paste a link to a YouTube video and it will replace the link with a box containing the video title and thumbnail. Clicking the box opens an embedded version of the video.

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idt3HoPz9io`

## User Content

Add a link to any **screenshots, artwork, videos, Workshop items, collections, guides, or Greenlight items** and they will be given a preview. Clicking will pop up a preview.

Screenshot: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=117886695`
Artwork: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=163988748`
Videos: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=178460483`
Workshop items: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=159186571`
Collections: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=95744629`
Guides: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=159458915`
Greenlight items: `http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=93777661`

## Inventory Items

Right click an item in your inventory and click *Copy Link Location*. Pasting that link in a discussions post (or even a chat window).

`http://steamcommunity.com/id/keavon/inventory/#440_2_1464041478`

## Trade Offer Buttons

A button to send a trade offer can be created by pasting a link to your public trade offers found under *Item Inventory » Trade Offers » Who can send me Trade Offers?*

`http://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=88225129&token=0FwymFEe`

## Emoticons

I'm not sure if this counts, but you can type the code for an emoticon which will appear in your post provided that it exists in your inventory.

`:tdealwithit:` [image: :tdealwithit:]

---

I'm sure there's more that I can't think of right now. I will update this if I find any more.

Answer (score 2):

To do this simply go in you inventory, right click an item and click 'Copy link address' then post it in your topic/comment :)
[image: Inventory]
[image: post]

Comment: Thanks! BTW, you didn't finish editing the second pic.

Comment: Yeah I noticed! Oh well xD
Hit me up whenever, I have no need for any of those coupons if you want them

Comment: You should crop those images.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to your inventory, right click on an item, choose copy link and paste it into the post as is.

You can get your public trade offer link by going to your inventory, trade offers and then "Who can send me Trade Offers?". You'll see your own link down towards the bottom under "Third-Party Sites".

[image: Who can send me Trade Offers?]